# android layout overlay issue

Tags: android, xml, layout, admob

I am a beginner in android.I made a flash game android app using a webview and integrated admob ad banner but it is overlaying the webview.I need it to appear like this pic http://i46.tinypic.com/2cosrjp.png
this is my code :

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/lay"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="a1513fab869115a"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `android:layout_below="+id/lay"` inside you webView view

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/lay"
android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

add `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` in ads view

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="a1513fab869115a"
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" />
```

Comment: Great !! can the ad banner size be decreased ??

Comment: android:layout_height="40dp" or whatever the size you can give after testing.

Comment: give me your email to contact you in the future !

Answer (score 0):

Even though RelativeLayout might be the first choice for many use cases, for this simple view I would use a [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html), that's much easier.

Answer (score 0):

i got the oppiste error, i want my app displayed as yours and i cant get it, i got the answer that u want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="355dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="000000000000000000"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tropas"
        android:layout_weight="1.01" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is my code and display Aadmob on top Not overlaying webview